# Zend Framework 2 TableGateway MAX query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

since few days i have a problem with mysql query using tablegateway and zf2 functions.

I would like to get max value of column `'reservation_spot'` where `'reservation_datetime' = &reservation_datetime`
The query shoud be like this

```
SELECT MAX(`reservation_spot`) FROM `reservation` WHERE `reservation_datetime`='2015-09-30 8:00'
```

I've tried many things to solve that problem but i can't

This is my function

```
public function getMaxValueWhereDate($reservation_datetime)
    {
        $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
        $select->columns(array(
            'maxValue' => new Expression('MAX(reservation_spot)')
        ));
        $select->where(array('reservation_datetime' => $reservation_datetime));

        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not retrieve max value");
        }

        return $row;
    }
```

plus this

```
$reservation->reservation_spot = $this->getMaxValueWhereDate($reservation_datetime);
$reservation->reservation_spot++;
```

After this when i run my form i get error:

> Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ' '55', '41', '1', 0,
>   '2015-09-08 16:23:27')' at line 1)

The Query from my function is

```
SELECT MAX(reservation_spot) AS `maxValue` FROM `reservation` WHERE `reservation_date` = '2015-09-30 08:00'
```

@UPDATE Solved, edited to

```
public function getMaxValueWhereDate($reservation_datetime)
{
    $sql = $this->tableGateway->getSql();
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->columns(array(
        'maxValue' => new Expression('MAX(reservation_spot)')
    ));
    $select->where(array('reservation_datetime' => $reservation_datetime));

    return $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
}
```

and

```
$reservation->reservation_spot = (int)$this->getMaxValueWhereDate($reservation_datetime);
```

Comment: what does the query looks like ? you can use tableGateway->getSqlStringFromSqlObject($select) to print the sql query

Comment: Did you properly "use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;" in your repository

Comment: The Query from my function is

    SELECT MAX(reservation_spot) AS `maxValue` FROM `reservation` WHERE `reservation_date` = '2015-09-30 08:00'

Comment: I'm not sure, the error message is linked with the sample of code you provide

Comment: I soved my query problem when i edited `$reservation->reservation_spot = $this->getMaxValueWhereDate($reservation_datetime);` to `$reservation->reservation_spot = (int)$this->getMaxValueWhereDate($reservation_datetime);` however my other line  `$reservation->reservation_spot++;` should increased by one, but in doesnt

Comment: return $row['maxValue'] should solve then instead of casting it.

Comment: not i have a "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Reservations\Model\Reservation as array in [...] this file on this line" but when i edit my function to (look at updated post) it works too, but incrementation still doesnt work

Comment: Oh ok, it's because your $row is directly an instance of reservation model. Make sure your reservation_spot is a public attribute otherwise you'll have to access it via getter and setter method. You can try $reservation->setReservationSpot($reservation->getReservationSpot()+1);

Comment: How the solution here can work as we are casting a ResultSet object?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a row result which is an *instance of your model* and not the *value* you want.

In your first example, change this line:

```php
return $row->maxValue;
```

You also **have to to declare the maxValue field in your model** or it won't be mapped.

Another possibility, if you don't need this field in your model, is to use an already existing field:

```
$select->columns(array(
    'reservation_spot' => new Expression('MAX(reservation_spot)')
));
```

And then:

```
return $row->reservation_spot;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2015-09-30 8:00';
$select = $this->getSql()->select()
           ->columns(array('Reservation ' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('MAX(reservation_spot)')))
           ->where("reservation_datetime ='$date'");
        $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
        $row = $resultSet->current();
```